# Casting in for-each-loop

Tags: java, casting

Consider the above code example.

Why the compiler complains about "incompatible types" in the for-each-loop and says:

```
B.java:10: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
            for (String k : a.m.keySet()) {
```

If I strip the type parameter  all compiles fine.

```
public class A<T> {

    Map<String,Field> m;

    void foo() {
        new B(this).foo();
    }
}

class B {

    A a;

    B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    void foo() {        
        for (String k : a.m.keySet()) { 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that your real class is exactly the same as in the example? Does your `Map` have type parameters, or is it a raw `Map`? If it does not have type parameters, then `keySet` would return a collection of `Object` instead of a collection of the key type.

Comment: Show us the real code. What is the type of the object you are iterating over in your real foreach?

Comment: To figure out why your code doesn't work, we really need to see the code that does not work, and not some approximation that does.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - we can hardly guess around. Posting an example that does something completely different (it works after all) is rather useless, I'm sure you agree

Comment: Ok Guys you got me. See my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No time to find the corresponding JLS part, but it's simple: If you declare a class with a type parameter and then use it without it, the compiler removes **all** generic declarations of the class. I.e.

```
public class A<T> {
    Map<String,Field> m;
}
```

becomes

```
public class A {
    Map m;
}
```

The fix is obvious: Instantiate A with a generic parameter or remove T.

Answer (score 0):

Inner field B.a must be concretized.
Try

```
class B {

    A<Object> a;
```